# How do I code an ajax function to receive a return code passed back from a controller method?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

From an ajax function, I call an MVC controller method and return a -1 if the method fails. How do I code the ajax function to receive the -1 so that I can execute a javascript alert?

```
function RejectButtonProcess()
{
    // This will execute the method in the specified controller. 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("NHPDAdminRejectAddress", "Home")',
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
        { 
           //alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
           alert("An error occurred during the reject process. Contact the IT department."); 
        }  
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the success callback:

```
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        // process the data
    },
```

The `data` variable coming back will contain the return code (probably in JSON, depending on how you set up your endpoint).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows,

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("NHPDAdminRejectAddress", "Home")',
    data: JSON.stringify(model), \\ Pass data if any
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        if(result == -1) { \\Check Result
            alert("Error");
        }
    },
    error: function () {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Although sending back a response and checking the data object in the callback (as explained above by @Richard and @Jatin) will work, I tend to follow the following pattern of rolling my own AjaxResult object, hydrating this object with the model state validity, the success state, as well as any data I need to pass back to the $.ajax success callback function. This enables a flexible and elegant solution in handling $.ajax requests.  For example:

```
// custom ajax request result class
public class AjaxResult
{
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, object> Data { get; set; }

    public AjaxResult()
    {           
        Data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }

    public void AddData(string dataKey, object dataValue)
    {
        if (dataKey != null && !Data.ContainsKey(dataKey))
        {
            Data.Add(dataKey, dataValue);
        }
    }
}

// controller
public ActionResult NhpdAdminRejectAddress(NhpdAdminViewModel model)
{
    AjaxResult result = new AjaxResult();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // do something
        result.AddData("Code", -1);
        result.IsValid = true;
        result.Success = true;
    }

    return Json(result);
}

// ajax post request
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("NHPDAdminRejectAddress", "Home")',
    data: JSON.stringify(model),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        if (result != null && result.Data != null && result.Data.Code != null)
        {
            int code = result.Data.Code;
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        // handle error
    }
});
```